# Python-Docx Inserting HTML into Docx

Tags: python, html, python-docx, italics

Is it possible to insert HTML into a Document using python-docx with styling applied?
The only thing I need to work are italics.

For example how to insert `"Today is <i>Saturday</i>."` with Saturday actually being inserted with italics?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
p = document.add_paragraph()
p.add_run('Today is ') 
p.add_run('Saturday').italic = True 
p.add_run('.')
```

The library doesn't understand html. You have to parse text yourself, separating italic text from non-italic text and add it to the document as shown above.

Comment: Okay Ill have to write a small function that does that.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, from your html document:

```
from htmldocx import HtmlToDocx

new_parser = HtmlToDocx()
new_parser.parse_html_file("html_filename", "docx_filename")
#Files extensions not needed, but tolerated
```